# how can we send/received frames in layer 2 (Using MAC address ) in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, kernel

I am doing research in parallel computing side in my master. we are creating a real TriBA-Network a Triple based architecture (for multi core processor network). For this i am working on network part. So i have to implement routing in this network on layer 2 level. i have done routing on layer 3 (network layer) using TCP\IP protocol. But we have to send/received frames (not packets) on layer 2.

Maybe i can use RAW socket for sending frames using network programming. but how we can received these frames in remote PC and forward. 
If somebody know about lower level communication that i can use for this task kindly share here. 
Advance Thank you.
Computer's are connected in that topology over LAN locally [TriBA Topology Network](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qsd3s932n5na00r/TriBA_NoC.png?dl=0)

Comment: These nodes on the topology - are there intermediate network devices (switches and routers) among them? Are there any such devices between the nodes?

Comment: I think the question "How to use raw socket?" is a bit broad.

Comment: @ZabojCampula i just mention RAW socket here in question because i have to work like that not same RAW socket. RAW socket uses MAC address instead of IP for communication on layer 2. So i do research on layer 2 level to implement our TriBA algorithm [link](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1691901/) in this TriBA Topology. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qsd3s932n5na00r/TriBA_NoC.png?dl=0)

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 No, these are computer's connected via LAN each contains quad port server Ethernet adapter [link](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ethernet-products/gigabit-server-adapters/ethernet-i350-server-adapter-brief.html?wapkw=i350) not routers and switches. As i describe above i have make routing on layer 3 by making Linux machine as routers. But now i have to work on layer 2 to make own like routing protocol. That's why i am wondering how we can communicate through MAC address in kernel level. Thanks for comment

Answer (score 1):

From the question it's not that clear why this is to be done *in kernel*.
However, I understand from the question that *some* lower-layer approach is needed. If there are some explicit latency or throughput requirements then it needs to be stated in the question.

So, if we postpone the hypothetical in-kernel approach, indeed, you may use `PF_PACKET` sockets to send them. The same way, using `PF_PACKET` sockets you may receive them at the remote side. However, typically, this still involves certain overhead since the kernel copies data between its own buffers and the socket buffers accessed by the user in the userland.
From this perspective you may consider [PACKET_MMAP](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt) technique to set up direct memory mapping to access data from kernel-side buffers. This might be a really good improvement in terms of, say, throughput, but it's rather controversial whether this will fit your need of *forwarding*.

Another one suggestion is to use some sort of like [data plane kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Plane_Development_Kit) (please find the link on that page) which may have a set of libraries designed specially for kernel-bypass networking (similar to `PACKET_MMAP`, but much better) and for certain tasks like *L2 forwarding*.

All in all, it is likely that you have enough tools to do what you need, however, a more detailed description would be better for understanding.

Comment: Thank you Bronislav Elizavetin for your suggestion. i will work on that you have suggested here.